# Como puedo llevar un dato alojado en una base de datos a mi código JavaScript utilizando Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Mi problema es que estoy intentando agregar un mapa de Google maps mediante JavaScript a mi pagina web, con el código JavaScript que mostrare a continuación, el problema que tengo es que quiero utilizar para la latitud y longitud del Google maps unas determinadas coordenadas que he guardado en el campo "latitude" y "length" del modelo Event. Imagino que algo tendré que hacer mediante Python pues es mi lenguaje de backend y estoy utilizando el framework Django. Si necesitais mas información comentarme y intentare ser mas detallado o lo que haga falta.

```
function iniciarMap(){
    var coord = {lat:-34.5956145, lng:-58.4431949};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: coord
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coord,
        map: map
    })
}
```

Codigo del modelo:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nombre")
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name='Contenido')
    image = models.ImageField(default='null', verbose_name="Imagen", upload_to="eventos")
    public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='¿Publicado?')
    latitude = models.CharField(default="null", max_length=50, verbose_name="Latitud")
    length = models.CharField(default="null", max_length=50, verbose_name="Longitud")
```

Comment: Creo que lo mejor sería tener una ruta que traiga esos datos y con JS haces una petición get para traerlos

Comment: de hecho tengo una view que manda los datos a la url "eventos/" donde carga una pagina html. en la pagina html se traer los datos utilizando las llaves y la variable ( {{event.latitude}} ). pero no se como traerlo al archivo js porque yo quiero traerlos al archivo js no al html

Comment: Cono dije, haces una petición get con JS, el navegador por defecto hace la petición get pero rendiría en html. Tu tienes que hacer con JS usando la api `fetch`

Comment: investigare acerca de ello

Comment: Si pusieras tu view podria ayudarte un poco más